L'espressione "lasciando che"
Ho incontrato l'espressione "lasciando che" leggendo la prima frase dell'introduzione di Tommaso Landolfi alla sua raccolta di poesie di Puškin:

Lasciando che o perché giudico inutile in ogni caso parlare di un poeta, per me il tradurre o appena il rileggere un qualunque scrittore è rendermelo come dire avverso.

Come si deve capire questa espressione qui? Capisco che si oppone all'alternativa "perché", cioè ci sono due opzioni e una delle opzioni è il fatto che lui giudica "inutile in ogni caso parlare di un poeta" è il motivo per il fatto che per lui "il tradurre...". Qual è l'altra opzione?  Possiamo sostituire "Lasciando che" con "Trascurando che" o le due espressioni hanno dei sensi diversi?

Formulo solo un'ipotesi, perché anche a me non è chiarissimo. Mi sembra che l'alternativa sia limiti alle prime parole: proverei a parafrasarlo con qualcosa come “ignorando/indipendentemente dal fatto che giudico inutile [...] o proprio per questo, per me il tradurre...”

Veramente Landolfi ha spesso una sintassi proprio contorta.

@Bruno: Si tratta della prima frase nell'introduzione a una sua traduzione di poemi de Puškin?

@Charo: Esatto, avrei dovuto aggiungere quest'informazione. L'aggiungo adesso.

I would have written Lasciando stare che […].

Non sappiamo cos'era scritto prima... Non conosco quell'autore, ma (soprattutto un tempo) c'era l'abitudine di comporre i discorsi in periodi ed un periodo poteva continuare il precedente, il ché: suona logico, no?
Leggendo quel singolo periodo la sensazione che provo è che l'iniziale "lasciando" si connette al discorso precedente, anziché fare da "premessa" a ciò che segue.
Secondo me nei periodi precedenti esprima "qualcosa", mentre in questo il suo discoroso prende una direzione diversa, marcata appunto dal "lasciando".
Quindi non va letto come funzionale o integrale a ciò che segue, se non (come ho già sentenziato) come pura premessa.

Non c'è nessun discorso precedente: si tratta della prima frase di un'introduzione, scritta dallo stesso Landolfi, a una sua traduzione di poesie di Puškin.

Lasciando che, vuoi perché giudico inutile replicare, vuoi perché lo sia davvero, resta il fatto che i discorsi non iniziano mai davvero in quel momento, ma sempre prima e altrove.

Come l'ha scritto @Charo, non c'è nessun discorso precedente. La cosa che mi interessa in questa risposta è che mi sembra que, se ho capito bene, qui il "che" si capisce come "questo", cioè "lasciando che" sarebbe una espressione da se stesso, quando io credevo che il "che" introduce una subordinata e lo leggevo così: "lasciando che giudico inutile in ogni caso parlare di un poeta". Non sono madrelingua italiana, però mi suona strano che "che" si può utilizzare come "questo" - ci sono dei casi dove "che" non introduce una subordinata ma si utilizza come "questo"?

Quando mentalmente traduci ed espandi il "che" (allo scopo di capire il senso di un discorso), capita che quella parola diventi un mondo intero.
La parola che designa la domanda, il "perché", è l'esempio più evidente.
Perché significa sia "why" che "because" e cosa dice?
Per-ché = per (quali motivi)
Ed ecco che salta fuori il "che" capace di rappresentare il mondo intero.
